# duplicating UDP stream via socat

Tags: linux, stream, socat

I'm developing some gateway product connected to host PC via USB, with embedded linux inside.
My task is read to read logs UDP stream from device file and to forward it both to remote host and to save it to file in my file system (ramfs)
I do this using the following command:

socat -b1450 -u /dev/ueservice0 - | tee -a /tmp/ModemFW.log | socat -b1450 -u - UDP4-DATAGRAM:${IPADDR}:4566

The problem is that when there's heavy data traffic (FTP) stream running on the same USB interface approx. half of the stream doesn't reach the destination, though the ModemFW.log file contains all the logs.
The weird thing is that if I don't save the logs to file on ramfs everything works fine and the host receives all the stream even with the same heavy traffic:

socat -b1450 -u /dev/ueservice0 UDP4-DATAGRAM:${IPADDR}:4566

Does anybody know what is the problem that tee causes that half of the packets get lost? Is there another way to do it?
Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Does the problem occur if you skip the `tee` part? And are you aware that UDP doesn't provide a reliable data transfer? I also expect the USB interface to be not reliable enough for high traffic.

Comment: Without the 'tee' everything works fine. Maybe there is some packet loss, but not half of the data. But I need also to save the same logs stream to the file in addition to forwarding it to the host. Do you have an idea how to do it without tee?

Comment: If you have fewer packet loss without `tee` then I guess your limited I/O throughput is the cause of the problem. I never used `socat` myself but it seems it can directly write to a file without the need to use `tee` by specifying `file:` as address.